# C# printing bitmap is blurry when printed on paper but clean when "printed" to PDF format

Tags: c#, printing, bitmap

I want to print UserControl that contains labels, barcode, and a datagridview but when I want to print it on paper it is blury. But when i print it to PDF it's clean. Here is my code:

```
        {
            Graphics g = control.CreateGraphics();
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(control.Width, control.Height, g);

            bitmap.SetResolution(bitmap.HorizontalResolution, bitmap.VerticalResolution);
             

            control.DrawToBitmap(bitmap, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, control.Width, control.Height));

            var pd = new PrintDocument();


            pd.PrintPage += (s, e) => e.Graphics.DrawImage(bitmap, 0, 0);
            PaperSize ps = new PaperSize();
            ps.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.A4;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
            pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false;
            
            pd.Print();
        }
```

Comment: If you want to print text or vector-type data, why do you use bitmaps? Raster graphics will inevitably involve some amount of processing and blurriness.

Comment: It would be my first printing and i found that.

Comment: But if you can suggest any better way to print i would be glad if you would share it with me. @JonasH

Comment: Try avoid any intermediate bitmap. In the `PrintPage`-event you have a graphics object, try to draw your rectangle to this object directly. I would expect some issues with size, scale etc, but these should be possible to solve.